# Adding time to curdate mysql

Tags: mysql, date, datetime, time

I have two columns, one is a datetime, and another is a time.
I need to add to the time column the CURDATE(), and compare with the datetime column.

```
SELECT b.rese_data, 
       a.period_ini, 
       a.period_end 
FROM   esp_time a, 
       rese b 
WHERE  a.week_day = WEEKDAY(NOW()) 
       AND a.period_ini <= NOW() 
       AND a.period_end >= NOW() 
       AND b.rese_data >= a.periodo_ini 
       AND b.rese_data <= a.periodo_fim
```

First i select the two period(time) which can be like :

```
period_ini = "12:00:00"
pediod_end = "17:00:00"
```

and then compare with the rese_data(datetime)

Comment: Not sure, but I think you'd want `CONCAT(CURDATE(), ' ', period_ini)`

Answer (score 0):

You need `ADDTIME(CURRENT_DATE, period_ini)` to get a particular time today.

If you want a particular time on a particular date, `ADDTIME(DATE(rese_data), period_ini)` will do it for you.

This `ADDTIME()` function adds a time to a datetime.

Answer (score 0):

You need to format your timestamp. For example: `date_format(current_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d 00:00:00')` and `date_format(current_timestamp, '%Y-%m-%d 23:59:59')`